# Viewing Multiple columns in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to code in two or more columns in ANDROID STUDIO at the same time?
For example: In Sublime Text 3, I can go to View>Layout>columns:2 to be able to see two open files at the same time and edit both of them. [This is a Screen Shot of two columns opened in sublime text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MHMb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can do it just by taking a Right-click on  the activity  to be multitasked from the activity draw displayed just above the Typing console(coding area) and choose the option "**Move to Right** ":

Answer (score 4):

Right click on file name at the top of the editor. And select either split vertically/horizontally to duplicate or move right/left